# How to check the type of AcroFields if different type of fields have same FieldName? ITextSharp

Tags: itext

If there is a checkBox and a TextBox which have the same FieldName. The Acrofields will use the FieldName as a Key.

How can I send appropriate value to different field? (true, false to CheckBox and text to TextBox)

The code below only works if there is no duplicate FieldName for different type of field

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(this._pdfInputPath);  
        AcroFields formFields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in formFields.Fields)
        {
            AcroFields.Item acroFieldItem = kvp.Value as AcroFields.Item;
            //TextField :4
            //CheckBox :2
            //RadioButton :3
            //ComboBox :6
            //ListBox :5
            //Button :1
            int fileType = formFields.GetFieldType(kvp.Key);
            string translatedFileName = formFields.GetTranslatedFieldName(kvp.Key);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In PDF, if two fields share a name, they share a value.  Period.

How did you even come by a form with two different field TYPES sharing the same name?  Acrobat won't let you.  iText probably isn't retentive enough to prevent it.